# Trying to understand how to get import re to work in pycharm

Tags: python, regex, pycharm

I'm going through a course at work for Python. We're using Pycharm, and I'm not sure if that's what the problem is.
Basically, I have to read in a text file, scrub it, then count the frequency of specific words. The counting is not an issue. (I looped through a scrubbed list, checked the scrubbed list for the specific words, then added the specific words to a dictionary as I looped through the list. It works fine).
My issue is really about scrubbing the data. I ended up doing successive scrubs to get to a final clean list. But when I read the documentation, I should be able to use regex or re and scrub my file with one line of code. No matter what I do, importing re, or regex I get errors that stop my code.

How can I write the below code pythonically?

```
    # Open the file in read mode
with open('chocolate.txt', 'r') as file:
    input_col = file.read().replace(',', '')

text3 = input_col.replace('.', '')
text2 = text3.replace('"', '')
text = text2.split()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a regular expression which looks something like this

import re

result = re.sub(r'("|.|,)', "", text)

print(result)

Here text is the string you would read from the text file
Hope this helps!

```
x = re.sub(r'("|\.|,)', "", str)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help you out :) .